# How could I solve these errors below?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new at python and I'm trying to run this piece of code that found in this link below:

http://benalexkeen.com/gradient-boosting-in-python-using-scikit-learn/

When I run the first two snippets I got a bunch of errors, could anyone please correct it for me, please?. I have data and I try to draw them like this in these two snippets.

These are the two piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import linear_model

# Mock data
x = np.arange(0, 60)
y = map(lambda x: x / 2 + (x // 10) % 2 * 20 * x / 5 + np.random.random() * 10, x)
x = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})

# Plot mock data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I got the errors that below:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7f1d946a4092> in <module>
      6 # Plot mock data
      7 plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
----> 8 plt.scatter(x, y)
      9 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, data, **kwargs)
   2862         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,
   2863         verts=verts, edgecolors=edgecolors, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2864         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2865     sci(__ret)
   2866     return __ret

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4170             edgecolors = 'face'
   4171 
-> 4172         self._process_unit_info(xdata=x, ydata=y, kwargs=kwargs)
   4173         x = self.convert_xunits(x)
   4174         y = self.convert_yunits(y)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_unit_info(self, xdata, ydata, kwargs)
   2134 
   2135         kwargs = _process_single_axis(xdata, self.xaxis, 'xunits', kwargs)
-> 2136         kwargs = _process_single_axis(ydata, self.yaxis, 'yunits', kwargs)
   2137         return kwargs
   2138 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_single_axis(data, axis, unit_name, kwargs)
   2116                 # We only need to update if there is nothing set yet.
   2117                 if not axis.have_units():
-> 2118                     axis.update_units(data)
   2119 
   2120             # Check for units in the kwargs, and if present update axis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in update_units(self, data)
   1465         """
   1466 
-> 1467         converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)
   1468         if converter is None:
   1469             return False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py in get_converter(self, x)
    185         if converter is None:
    186             try:
--> 187                 thisx = safe_first_element(x)
    188             except (TypeError, StopIteration):
    189                 pass

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in safe_first_element(obj)
   1633         except TypeError:
   1634             pass
-> 1635         raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not support generators "
   1636                            "as input")
   1637     return next(iter(obj))

RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input
```

The results that I'm expecting to get below in this picture

[image: here]

Comment: Which version of python are you using? The code works for me on python 2.7

Comment: @Dan I use Python 3.7.3

Comment: works just fine on python 2.7

Comment: I guess this code was written for Python 2.7. `map` returns a list in python 2.7, but an iterator in Python 3

Comment: @lenik As I told you i'm new to python. I got some solutions below my dear. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `plt.scatter(x, y)` with `plt.scatter(x, list(y))`.

The value of y represents a generator function, but matplotlib needs a list here. That worked for me on python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Convert `map` object to `list`, because in `python 3` is returned iterator:

```
y = list(map(lambda x: x / 2 + (x // 10) % 2 * 20 * x / 5 + np.random.random() * 10, x))
```